# Names of pre-1918 letters

Tags: буквы, алфавит, дореформенная-орфография

What were the names of the Russian letters и and i in the pre-1918 Russian alphabet?

Comment: what have you research showed so far and why you've decided to ask here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Поскольку ответы в одно предложение, насколько я помню, против правил (в таких случаях рекомендуется дать больше информации), даю название всех букв.

Названия букв в старой орфографии.  В квадратных скобках сама буква, если она не совпадает с первой буквой названия.  В круглых скобках вариант названия или (курсивом) моё примечание.

азъ, буки, вѣди, глаголь, добро, есть, живѣте, земля, иже (и восьмеричное), i (i десятеричное), и съ краткой (*не уверен, что считалось отдельной буквой*), како, люди, мыслѣте, нашъ, онъ, покой, рцы, слово, твердо, укъ, фертъ, хѣръ, цы, червь, ша, ща, еръ `[ъ]`, еры `[ы]`, ерь `[ь]`, ять `[ѣ]`, э (оборотное э), ю, я, ѳита (*в современной орфографии - фита*), ижица `[ѵ]`.

Правописание названий букв по книге "[Россiйская грамматика](https://www.runivers.ru/bookreader/book192769/#page/42/mode/1up)" Ломоносова, стр. 41-42 в источнике. Не все буквы у него есть, правописание названий других букв по [Russian alphabet в английской википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet).

Ижица была отменена Петром I, потом то вводилась, то отменялась, к концу 19 века формально осталась, но в грамматике 1870-х пишется, что она употребляется только в одном слове : мѵро.  Я не уверен, правильно ли было писать ижица или ѵжица.

PS: старые названия стали выходить из употребления и заменяться новыми с конца 19 века. Так, название "твёрдый знак" впервые употребляется в Корпусе русского языка в 1875 году (путевые заметки), а второй раз в 1896 году ("Олеся" Куприна). "Ер" в тот период употребляется только в речи детей и малограмотных персонажей, например:

> Дело идёт хорошо, Люба быстро постигает премудрость чтения и письма,
>   пачкает чернилами и пальцы и нос, Ванюшка хмурится, басит ещё гуще,
>   чем летом, пишет вместо буквы «р» везде твёрдый знак, верёвка у него
>   выходит въевка, верхом ― въхом. Когда учительница объясняет, что это
>   не так, он солидно спорит: ― А как же? «Ер» ― в нём сразу две буквы, я
>   и пишу ер, чтобы скорее было написано… Нету ера? А дедушка говорит ―
>   есть он? В конце слов? Мм… [Максим Горький. Большая любовь (1912)]

Comment: Ижица использовалась в словах греческого происхождения писавшихся через ипсилон: "мѵро", "ѵссод", "сѵнод". Постепенно [все они стали писаться](http://bibliotekar.ru/bei/106.htm) через десятеричное *"и".*

Comment: @Vitaly - через восьмеричное "и".  Десятеричное - это i.

Answer (score 4):

They're named [**Иже**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98) and [**І**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86_(%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)) (pronounced as [и] i surmise) or **И восьмеричное**  and **И десятиричное** respectively  <sup>[**[ 1 ]**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0#%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)</sup>  due to numerical values used to be assigned to them <sup>[**[ 2 ]**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)</sup>

[image]